# HttpAsyncClient zero copy download from S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3

Having such problem setup:
1) Microservice should stream files to clients via http 
2) Files stored in S3 bucket 
3) Aws sdk only supports downloading to application host first (or just buffering in-memory)

Does any one have working example of zero-copy async streaming from s3 to client?

Comment: There's usually no reason to stream files from S3 through your application, since you can authorize a direct download with [pre-signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).  Does this not work for you?

Comment: One of the requirements is not to expose file location to the client. Mostly for security purposes. Another thing we want to perform very specific ownership checks before allowing download, so streaming through application is necessary.

Comment: The first requirement is frivolous.  Location is not useful without credentials.  The ownership checks can be done *before generating* the signed URL -- which you would do *per request* with a short expiration time, or simply refusing to generate it if the request isn't authorized -- and, if authorized, returning it to the client as a `302` redirect.  If done over HTTPS, this is no less secure than what you propose.

Comment: It's given requirement that direct url/path/bucket name in s3 should not be exposed. Please, let's get back to original question, do you have working example of file streaming from s3?